# Time loop for retrieving data from web - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am succesfully retrieving data from web by using:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.org")
Dim o As Object

Dim dizi As String() = result.Split(New String() {",,,"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
' urls on the webpage are seperated with ,,, so it gets the first website
Dim urladdress As String = dizi(0)

o.Navigate2(urladdress)
```

However, I need to add time loop for it. For example, it need to retrieve the data on every 5 minute. Tried this without anyluck:

```
Imports System.Timers
Public Class TimerRequest
    Private Shared aTimer As Timer
    Private Shared o as Object
        Public Shared Sub Main()
             aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(300000) ' 5 minutes
             AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
             aTimer.Enabled = True
        End Sub  
        Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

'----------------------------------------

    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.org")
    Dim o As Object

    Dim dizi As String() = result.Split(New String() {",,,"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    ' urls on the webpage are seperated with ,,, so it gets the first website
    Dim urladdress As String = dizi(0)

    o.Navigate2(urladdress)

'----------------------------------------

        End Sub  
 End Class
```

These are the errors

![enter image description here][1]

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: what does `without anyluck` mean? does it crash? does the timer fire?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for doing this.

Here is the entire amount of code you need:

```
Dim subscription = _
    Observable _
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0)) _
        .StartWith(-1L) _
        .SelectMany( _
            Observable _
                .Using( _
                    Function() New WebClient(), _
                    Function(wc) _
                        wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.example.org") _
                            .ToObservable())) _
        .Select(Function(result) _
            result.Split(New String() {",,,"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)) _
        .Subscribe(Sub(urladdress) o.Navigate2(urladdress))
```

This will automatically download your page and parse the `urladdress` every 5 minutes.

The nice thing is that you can call `subscription.Dispose()` to turn off the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Sleep method within a loop?

```
For i = 1 To 5 

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000) '// 5 mins in milliseconds

'// Do Something

Next i
```

Comment: That just sleep. I want it to check/retrieve the data on every 5 minutes.

Comment: See edit, I meant to use within a loop to pause for 5 minutes

Comment: It will do that only 5 times right ? So how about making an infinete loop ?

Comment: Infinite Loops are generally a bad idea, you should have some sort of test in place to decide when the loop should start/stop but if you really want an infinite loop just change the `For i = 1 To 5` to `Do` and change the `Next i` to `Loop`

Comment: Just need to add this, there is an infinite function will be running in that ' // do something place. Does this still work ?

Comment: No, as soon as the code steps into the 'infinite function' it will not step out again to repeat the next step in the loop. Instead, place the `Sleep` command within your 'infinite function'